# OpenWeatherMap Icon showing code instead of sprite

Tags: jquery

I am working with OpenWeatherMap.  Everything else is coming in properly (i.e. temperature, city name, weather description, etc.)  but for some reason I cannot get the Icon sprite to appear, instead I'm loading the icon code.  Any ideas where I went wrong?

jQuery...

```
var long;
var lat;
lat = position.coords.latitude;
long = position.coords.longitude;

var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=79b001616877b59c717616181ee219ec";

$.getJSON(api, function(info) {
    var weatherIcon = info.weather[0].icon;
    $('#weatherIcon').html(weatherIcon);
```

HTML...

```
<h3 id="weatherIcon"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to post the icon calling part of your code or you forgot to call the icon.
`info.weather[0].icon` will give you "Weather Icon ID". To get the weather icon see this [link](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions).

```
var iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherIcon + ".png";
```

iconURL will be where your icon image is.